# Is there a service to edit css and save file to server for use on our website?

Tags: css

We use a 3rd party service for our directory - until now they've included a CSS editor which saves to file and then the CSS path is used in our template. Recently they've removed this so now we cannot edit our CSS file.

**I am now looking for a service which offers a FILE MANAGER (HTML/CSS EDITOR) where we can update our CSS > save to file > obtain path and put this into our template.**

We use imagekit.io so one option is to edit the CSS in a txt document and re-upload to imagekit.io but this is a time consuming process.

Thankyou :)

Answer (score 0):

After some thought it's probably easiest to copy CSS into a .txt file , rename to .css and upload into imagekit.io for the file path.